# User account password. Stuck in guest forever?

Tags: password, password-recovery, guest-session

So, the thing is I created a new admin account, deleted the old one, but pressed "lock" before setting a password for it. Now I try to unlock it and it asks me for a password I've never set.

I did this while in a guest session.

Ideas?

Answer (score 5):

How To Reset Lost User Account Password For Ubuntu:

If you forget your password and cannot use another account to login and change it you can do the following instead.

1. Boot up & after bios but before bootloader hold down shift
2. Choose entry that says recovery mode and hit enter (Sometimes this entry is under Advanced Boot Options)
3. Scroll down to root and hit enter
4. type:
   mount -rw -o remount /
5. type:
   passwd username

replace "username" with the name of the account you are trying to change the password for.

1. You will be prompted to enter a new password, do so, and then you will be asked for it again so type it again.
2. Type:
   halt -p

This will shut down your computer, then reboot and login.

sincerely, tapthoseshoesandwish

Sources:
http://candlelight.any.djun.net/x/1/index.php?topic=535.0